# undefined property 'bind' when using expected conditions

Tags: javascript, angularjs, webdriver, protractor

I'm trying to use the expected conditions function to make protractor wait for the presence of items on a page before continuing.

http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=ExpectedConditions

I have followed the example in the docs, but I am getting an error about an undefined property.

This seems to be the case when using any expected condition, not just related to the presenceOf function I am using here:

```
var EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions
var pixels = element.all(by.repeater('item in items'))
var pixelsLoaded = EC.presenceOf(pixels)

browser.wait(pixelsLoaded,10000)
```

> Failed: Cannot read property 'bind' of undefined
>     Stack:
>       TypeError: Cannot read property 'bind' of undefined
>           at [object Object].ExpectedConditions.presenceOf (/foo/bar/node_modules/gulp-protractor/node_modules/protractor/lib/expectedConditions.js:233:33)
>           at Env. (/foo/bar/app/features/pixelmanager/test/pixelManagerPOTest.js:48:31)
>           at /foo/bar/node_modules/gulp-protractor/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/jasminewd2/index.js:95:14
>           at [object Object].promise.ControlFlow.runInFrame_ (/foo/bar/node_modules/gulp-protractor/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver/promise.js:1877:20)
>           at [object Object].promise.ControlFlow.runEventLoop_ (/foo/bar/node_modules/gulp-protractor/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver/promise.js:1755:8)
>           at [object Object]. (/foo/bar/node_modules/gulp-protractor/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver/promise.js:2056:12)
>           at goog.async.run.processWorkQueue (/foo/bar/node_modules/gulp-protractor/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/goog/async/run.js:125:21)
>           at runMicrotasksCallback (node.js:337:7)
>           at process._tickCallback (node.js:355:11)
>       From: Task: Run it in control flow
>           at Object. (/foo/bar/node_modules/gulp-protractor/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/jasminewd2/index.js:94:33)
>       ==== async task ====
>       Error
>           at Suite. (/foo/bar/app/features/pixelmanager/test/pixelManagerPOTest.js:44:5)
>           at Object. (/foo/bar/app/features/pixelmanager/test/pixelManagerPOTest.js:9:1)
>           at Module._compile (module.js:460:26)
>           at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
>           at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
>           at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Fixed by removing the improper call to `all`:

```
var pixels = element(by.repeater('item in items'));
```