# Failed: Cannot read property 'bind' of undefined Protractor

Tags: javascript, angularjs, binding, protractor

Getting a Failed: Cannot read property 'bind' of undefined

Page Object class:

```
this.popupToastIP = function(){
element.all(by.className('toast-success toast ng-trigger ng-trigger-
flyInOut')).then(function(){
element(by.className('toast-success toast ng-trigger ng-trigger-flyInOut')).getText(); 
});
```

Test spec:

```
browser.wait(EC.visibilityOf(publisher_whitelist_page.popupToastIP),5000);
expect(publisher_whitelist_page.popupToastIP.toEqual('Ip address removed'));
```

Have tried removing the 'all' but to no avail - still with same error (followed advice of post [undefined property 'bind' when using expected conditions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29969308/undefined-property-bind-when-using-expected-conditions/29971548#29971548)

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

Kirsty

**EDIT**

Tried adding bind but again to no avail.

```
this.popupToastIP = function(){
element.all(by.className('toast-success toast ng-trigger ng-trigger-
flyInOut')).then(function(){
element(by.className('toast-success toast ng-trigger ng-trigger-
flyInOut')).getText();
}).bind(this);
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You code is wrong, it dose no matter with protractor or other stuff. Another thing could you indent your code for others easy to read.

**1)** What the final pupose of this function, to get text from an element or to 
find an element?

```
this.popupToastIP = function(){
    element.all(by.className('toast-success toast ng-trigger ng-trigger-flyInOut'))
    .then(function(){
        element(by.className('toast-success toast ng-trigger ng-trigger-flyInOut'))
        .getText(); 
    });
}
```

**Issue 1** 
why you find element by same class name twice, the element.all(xxx) is redundant, because you no use its result in the following then().

**Issue 2** 
you not return value for function, but your code in Test Spec require it has return value.

**2)** Your code in Test Spec as below, require `popupToastIP` return an element and the text of element, they are conflict already.

```
browser.wait(EC.visibilityOf(publisher_whitelist_page.popupToastIP),5000); // require return an element
expect(publisher_whitelist_page.popupToastIP.toEqual('Ip address removed')); // require return text of element
```

**Issue 1** 
you decleared the `popupToastIP` as a function, you missed `()` behind it. It's no possbile for a function will be visible on page and equal to 'Ip address removed'

try below code

```
// Page Object
this.popupToastIP = element(by.className('toast-success toast ng-trigger ng-trigger-flyInOut'));

// Test Spec
browser.wait(EC.visibilityOf(publisher_whitelist_page.popupToastIP),5000);
expect(publisher_whitelist_page.popupToastIP.getText()).toEqual('Ip address removed'));
```

Comment: Tried code - but getting the following error - Failed: Wait timed out after 5001ms

Answer (score 0):

So the issue may be because `bind` is not available under the `Protractor.js` file.
You have to provide definition of `bind` before writing your test case in the same file like this.

```
if (!Function.prototype.bind) {
  Function.prototype.bind = function(oThis) {
    if (typeof this !== 'function') {
    // closest thing possible to the ECMAScript 5
    // internal IsCallable function
    throw new TypeError('Function.prototype.bind - what is trying to be bound is not callable');
}

var aArgs   = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1),
    fToBind = this,
    fNOP    = function() {},
    fBound  = function() {
      return fToBind.apply(this instanceof fNOP
             ? this
             : oThis,
             aArgs.concat(Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments)));
    };

if (this.prototype) {
  // Function.prototype doesn't have a prototype property
  fNOP.prototype = this.prototype; 
}
fBound.prototype = new fNOP();

return fBound;
```

};
}

Comment: Have you checked the definition of `bind` under `Protractor.js` properly. If yes then will you please share that line of code at which its returning this error.

Comment: Yes I have also added your code above.  The Test spec is throwing the error

Comment: You have to share that peice of code in which you are originally using `bind` not to add this line `.bind(this); `.

Comment: function.bind 1.1.1 is avaliable in my package.-lock.json file - so it does have it built into protractor - I copied your piece of code as above and put it in my protractor.conf.js file - got the same error then tried to put it in my test spec file - still same error